# Redirect both stdin and stdout in bash to different files

Tags: bash

I need to make some bash script that stores all its input to file/pipe and reads its output from other file pipe and run forever. First part is like `cat - > pipein` and second is like `cat pipeout`. But how to make both parts simultaneously?

I also tried to mess with additional file descriptors but with no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer!

```
#!/bin/bash
cat pin &
cat >pout
wait
```

Comment: You do not need the parentheses.

Comment: The trick is in parentheses. Without them process stays in first `cat` transferring stdin to pipe and never starts transfer `pin` pipe to stdout. I need both ways in the same time.

Comment: In all cases, `cat` will copy its input to its output until it hits the end of file.  At this time, I fail to see why parentheses would change the behaviour of your script, as the same input is captured (to the best of my knowledge) whether you use parentheses or not.  Also, at least on my system, using `-` or no argument for `cat` makes no difference, as both cause stdin to be read.  If it works for you, then great, but I am not convinced it works for the reason you think it does.

Comment: By the way, I tested your script (with and without parentheses) on my system, and parentheses have no impact.  Are you sure you are not launching the first `cat` in the background (e.g. with `&` at the end)?

Comment: Without parenthesis it reads stdin up to EOF then starts reading pin. With them it does both at once. The feature is described here: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/subshells.html And no, I don't add `&`.

Comment: Test like this. Shell 1: type `mkfifo pin; mkfifo pout; (cat - >pout); (cat pin)`. Shell 2: type `cat - >pin`. Shell 3: type `cat pout`. Shell 2: type `hello`. Shell 1: see `hello` and type `hello back`. Shell 3: see `hello back`. Can be repeated many times.

Comment: I do not know why you call your FIFOs `pin` and `pout`, as they both are in and out, but that does not really matter. Following your instructions, get the result I am expecting, the only thing that is displayed is the "hello back", as shell 1 is writing to `pout` (its first command) and shell 3 is reading from `pout`.  Shell 2 is writing to `pin`, but no one is reading `pin`.  If you get a different result, then your shell is not doing the same thing as mine.

Comment: As for the manual, could you let me know which specific portion indicates sub-shells have the effect of creating parallel processing?  I work all the time with subshells, and this would be something entirely new to me.

Comment: Third paragraph: "A shell script can itself launch subprocesses. These subshells let the script do parallel processing, in effect executing multiple subtasks simultaneously."

Comment: I think you are misreading this statement.  It is true that subshells are required in order to perform parallel processing, but it does not mean that a subshell will, by default, execute in parallel.  In your document, see "Example 21-3. Running parallel processes in subshells".  The parallel execution requires the use of `&` to put the subshell in the background, as the default behavior of the shell is to wait for a subshell to finish before continuing execution.

Comment: You are right! I've misread docs. I'll fix my answer now. New version is working.